# HTML5 File API size issue in Safari

Tags: html, file-upload, safari

I have a drag and drop upload script which works fine on chrome and firefox. However, on Safari, it has an issue with retrieving the file size. It returns 0 bytes for the file size, but strangely, it will occasionally return the correct file size. This is around 1 out of every 10 times.

I am getting the files list via a drop event like so:

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
alert(files[0].size);
```

And upon trying to use the size method, I get 0 bytes in return. Does anyone know why this is happening?